# Allocate nr over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers:

```
var arr = [4.49, 4.03, 3.47, 3.05, 2.98, 2.94]
```

I want to allocate 2.89 to the array by adding to the numbers in the array in consecutive order. At the same time it needs to be assured that none of the numbers become to exceed 4.9.
The desired output should be the following array:

```
var arr2 = [4.9, 4.9, 4,9, 3.65, 3.05, 2.98, 2.94];
```

Anyone an idea for the respective JS code to transform the array likewise.

Comment: sorry, You should google it and find an answer "js sort array of floats" and "js filter by maximum number"

Comment: `const arr = [4.49, 4.03, 3.47, 3.05, 2.98, 2.94].sort((a, b) => (b - a)).filter(a => a <= 4.9)`

Comment: Can you explain a little more how that output is calculated? why `3.65`? Where it comes from? and why some number aren't changed?

Comment: this question is not about sorting, but about dispersing a value to some items until a wanted limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the number plus the sum to distribute is greater than the max value and return either the adjusted value or the value with the rest of the sum to distribute.

> ```
>                                             sum
> ------  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
> source  4.49  4.03  3.47  3.05  2.98  2.94
>  delta  0.41  0.87  1.43  0.18  0.00  0.00  2.89
> result  4.90  4.90  4.90  3.23  2.98  2.94
> ```

```js
var array = [4.49, 4.03, 3.47, 3.05, 2.98, 2.94],
    max = 4.9,
    sum = 2.89,
    result = array.map(v =>
        (vs => (sum = vs > max && vs - max, Math.min(vs, max)))
        (v + sum)
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

A bit more readable.

```js
var array = [4.49, 4.03, 3.47, 3.05, 2.98, 2.94],
    max = 4.9,
    sum = 2.89,
    result = array.map(v => {
        var temp;
        if (v + sum > max) {
            sum -= max - v;
            return max;
        } else {
            temp = v + sum;
            sum = 0;
            return temp;
        }
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm wondering how you figure out the goal from this: _The desired output should be the following array: `var arr2 = [4.9, 4.9, 4,9, 3.65, 3.05, 2.98, 2.94];`_. Anyway, good for you, bad for him. A clear question should be provided in first place...

Comment: @Shidersz, that is, i don't look at numbers, but what happens with the given vector and the new vector. some op's tend to ask with wrong numbers, but with a real problem, which is solvable by finding a solution and then the error.